# Echo command on unbind wont work with sudo, "Permission denied"

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I'm creating a service in CPP that detect a connection of USB and block it if it's mass storage.

To do so, I'm using `echo "{USB}-{PORT}" >> sys/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` and it remove the USB.

the thing is, its only working after `sudo -i` and using CPP system command wont let me run it as root. Plus I am unable to use the command like so : `sudo echo "{USB}-{PORT}" >> sys/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`, Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell interprets the >> within the current user prior to executing the sudo. That is, it tries to open the file as the current user and THEN executes sudo with the file open for standard out. That's why you get the access violation.

You could produce a shell script that does the echo >> part and sudo execute the script.

You could run your service as root.